# Oracle get date formatted as string between two dates

Tags: oracle

I am trying to work with 2 formatted dates, if I have TO_DATE('20160101' YYMMDD) and TO_DATE('20160104', YYMMDD) I would like to receive this output:

```
20160101
20160102
20160103
20160104
```

Is there a fast way to achieve this without using PL/SQL?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format mask in `to_date()` must be enclosed within single quotes too.

To produce the output in string format you need to apply `to_char()` with the same format mask.

```
select to_char(to_date('20160101', 'YYYYMMDD') + level - 1, 'YYYYMMDD') as dt
from   dual
connect by level <= 1 + to_date('20160104', 'YYYYMMDD') - to_date('20160101', 'YYYYMMDD')
;


DT     
--------
20160101
20160102
20160103
20160104
```

Comment: Yes sorry I did wrong the format between English and Italian date time so it wasn't working, thank you anyway it work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE '2016-01-01' + LEVEL - 1
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= DATE '2016-01-04' - DATE '2016-01-01' + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I need the same date format: '20160102' etc.. not the date

Comment: @Chrix1387 Then just use `TO_CHAR( datevalue, format_mask )` to format the strings and/or `TO_DATE( stringvalue, format_mask )` to get the dates from the strings.

Comment: `connect by level ` is correct way to do this, if you need another format  @Chrix1387 then just format the result with `to_char(mydate,'RRRRMMDD' )`

Comment: @Plirkee - why RRRR and not YYYY?

Comment: @mathguy just a habit, I guess ;-) I far as I remember, I had once or twice not desirable conversion with `YYYY`