# Based on Column Day concatenated with Date as Heading

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, unpivot

I have the data from my table as shown below

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ PROD_ID ║ START_DATE ║ TOT_HOURS   ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ PR220   ║ 19-Sep-17  ║ 0           ║
║ PR2230  ║ 19-Sep-17  ║ 2           ║
║ PR9702  ║ 19-Sep-17  ║ 3           ║
║ PR9036  ║ 19-Sep-17  ║ 0.6         ║
║ PR9036  ║ 18-Sep-17  ║ 3.4         ║
║ PR9609  ║ 18-Sep-17  ║ 5           ║
║ PR91034 ║ 18-Sep-17  ║ 4           ║
║ PR7127  ║ 18-Sep-17  ║ 0           ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Based on the `START_DATE`, could it be possible to have headings with Day concatenated with Date?

Expected output is

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦════════╦════════╦═══════════╗
║ PROD_ID ║ START_DATE ║ MON-18 ║ TUE-19 ║ TOT_HOURS ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║ PR220   ║ 19-Sep-17  ║        ║ 0      ║ 0         ║
║ PR2230  ║ 19-Sep-17  ║        ║ 2      ║ 2         ║
║ PR9702  ║ 19-Sep-17  ║        ║ 3      ║ 3         ║
║ PR9036  ║ 19-Sep-17  ║        ║ 0.6    ║ 0.6       ║
║ PR9036  ║ 18-Sep-17  ║ 3.4    ║        ║ 3.4       ║
║ PR9609  ║ 18-Sep-17  ║ 5      ║        ║ 5         ║
║ PR91034 ║ 18-Sep-17  ║ 4      ║        ║ 4         ║
║ PR7127  ║ 18-Sep-17  ║ 0      ║        ║ 0         ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩════════╩════════╩═══════════╝
```

Table structure and data

```
CREATE TABLE PROD_TIMINGS
(
  PROD_ID     VARCHAR2(12 BYTE),
  START_DATE  DATE,
  TOT_HOURS   NUMBER
);

SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into PROD_TIMINGS
   (PROD_ID, START_DATE, TOT_HOURS)
 Values
   ('PR220', TO_DATE('09/19/2017 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 0);
Insert into PROD_TIMINGS
   (PROD_ID, START_DATE, TOT_HOURS)
 Values
   ('PR2230', TO_DATE('09/19/2017 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 2);
Insert into PROD_TIMINGS
   (PROD_ID, START_DATE, TOT_HOURS)
 Values
   ('PR9702', TO_DATE('09/19/2017 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 3);
Insert into PROD_TIMINGS
   (PROD_ID, START_DATE, TOT_HOURS)
 Values
   ('PR9036', TO_DATE('09/19/2017 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 0.6);
Insert into PROD_TIMINGS
   (PROD_ID, START_DATE, TOT_HOURS)
 Values
   ('PR9036', TO_DATE('09/18/2017 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 3.4);
Insert into PROD_TIMINGS
   (PROD_ID, START_DATE, TOT_HOURS)
 Values
   ('PR9609', TO_DATE('09/18/2017 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 5);
Insert into PROD_TIMINGS
   (PROD_ID, START_DATE, TOT_HOURS)
 Values
   ('PR91034', TO_DATE('09/18/2017 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 4);
Insert into PROD_TIMINGS
   (PROD_ID, START_DATE, TOT_HOURS)
 Values
   ('PR7127', TO_DATE('09/18/2017 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 0);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15491661/1509264

Comment: @MT0 Not sure why this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql

Comment: Because you appear to want to generate dynamic columns based on a pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without using dynamic SQL to make the query.

But if you are willing to hardcode the values then:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/115d7/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE PROD_TIMINGS( PROD_ID, START_DATE, TOT_HOURS ) AS
SELECT 'PR220',   DATE '2017-09-19', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PR2230',  DATE '2017-09-19', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PR9702',  DATE '2017-09-19', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PR9036',  DATE '2017-09-19', 0.6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PR9036',  DATE '2017-09-18', 3.4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PR9609',  DATE '2017-09-18', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PR91034', DATE '2017-09-18', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PR7127',  DATE '2017-09-18', 0 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT PROD_ID,
       START_DATE,
       CASE START_DATE WHEN DATE '2017-09-18' THEN TOT_HOURS END AS "MON-18",
       CASE START_DATE WHEN DATE '2017-09-19' THEN TOT_HOURS END AS "TUE-19",
       TOT_HOURS
FROM   PROD_TIMINGS
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/115d7/1/0)**:

```
| PROD_ID |           START_DATE | MON-18 | TUE-19 | TOT_HOURS |
|---------|----------------------|--------|--------|-----------|
|   PR220 | 2017-09-19T00:00:00Z | (null) |      0 |         0 |
|  PR2230 | 2017-09-19T00:00:00Z | (null) |      2 |         2 |
|  PR9702 | 2017-09-19T00:00:00Z | (null) |      3 |         3 |
|  PR9036 | 2017-09-19T00:00:00Z | (null) |    0.6 |       0.6 |
|  PR9036 | 2017-09-18T00:00:00Z |    3.4 | (null) |       3.4 |
|  PR9609 | 2017-09-18T00:00:00Z |      5 | (null) |         5 |
| PR91034 | 2017-09-18T00:00:00Z |      4 | (null) |         4 |
|  PR7127 | 2017-09-18T00:00:00Z |      0 | (null) |         0 |
```

Comment: I have the start date and end date passed as parameters, so having these two dates can any way avoid the hardcoding?

Comment: I have to avoid hardcoding of dates and days.

Comment: You cannot use dynamic values in a pivot or as column aliases - you will either need to use hardcoded values or dynamic SQL to generate the query (with hardcoded values in the generated query). I have linked to a question on dynamic pivoting and if this is what you require then the question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: How can I use dynamic SQL generate the query?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23698873/1509264) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43569574/1509264) in the question I linked.

Comment: I have another question, is it possible to show the Day as heading based on the parameters Start and End Date?

Comment: You can use a [row generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39641871/1509264) to generate all the possible days and then just feed that into your dynamic SQL for the pivot.

Comment: Can you please have a look a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441419/dynamic-query-for-pivot-in-clause)?